# Divisor Function Analytic Continuation

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, divisor-counting-function

I'm trying to define the divisor function $d(k)$ over a larger domain than the integers but the result I produce appears to converge nowhere, including the integer points i originally expected it to Here is my process:

Consider: $$G(x) =  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{1}{1-x^k} - 1 \right] = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} d(i)x^i $$

Observe therefore that  $$ d(w) =\frac{1}{ \Gamma(w+1)}\frac{d^{(w)}G}{dx^{(w)}}[0]$$

Note: $$\frac{1}{1-x^k} = \frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \frac{1}{1-e^{2i\pi(\frac{j}{k})}x}$$

$$ d(w) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(w+1)}\frac{d^{(w)}G}{dx^{(w)}} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(w+1)}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{d^{(w)}}{dx^{(w)}} \left[ \frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \frac{1}{1-e^{2i\pi(\frac{j}{k})}x} - 1  \right]\right][0]$$

If we let $w \in \mathbb{N}$ then this simplifies to

$$ d(w) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(w+1)}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{d^{(w)}}{dx^{(w)}} \left[ \frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \frac{1}{1-e^{2i\pi(\frac{j}{k})}x}  \right]\right][0]= $$
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(w+1)}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[  \frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \frac{(-1)^w \Gamma(w+1)e^{2i\pi w(\frac{j}{k})}}{(1-e^{2i\pi(\frac{j}{k})}x)^w}  \right][0]$$

Cancelling out the gamma terms we have

$$ d(w)= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[  \frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \frac{(-1)^w e^{2i\pi w (\frac{j}{k})}}{(1-e^{2i\pi(\frac{j}{k})}x)^w}  \right][0]$$

Now setting $x=0$ yields

$$ d(w) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[  \frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} (-1)^w e^{2i\pi w (\frac{j}{k})} \right]$$

Factoring out common terms:

$$ d(w) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{(-1)^w}{k} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}   e^{2i\pi w (\frac{j}{k})} \right]$$

Applying Geometric Series formula:

$$ d(w) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{(-1)^w}{k} \frac{1 - e^{2 i \pi w}}{1 - e^{\frac{2 wi\pi}{k}}} \right]$$

Which factors out nicely now as

$$ d(w) = (-1)^w (1 - e^{2 wi \pi}) \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[   \frac{1}{k- ke^{\frac{2 wi\pi}{k}}} \right]$$

But it's unclear that this is well defined as the denominator seems to tend to 0 as k tends to infinity qualitatively. Perhaps evaluating this as some type of limit is necessary

Comment: Not sure this helps, but I think that
$$
\frac 1{1-x^k}=\frac1k \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac1{1-e^{2\pi i j/k}x}
$$
instead of what you had. In other words, you are missing the factor $1/k$, and something went wrong with the set of roots of unity.

Comment: yea i don't know why i was so hell bent on avoiding the sbutration on the bottom, let me include it and see where it goes

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen sorry for the delay have been doin this out of a tiny phone screen. What are your thoughts on the new derivation